# Why enum is accessible using scope resolution operator?

Tags: c++, enums

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Sample{
public:
   enum{ x = 10 };
};

int main(){
   cout<<Sample::x<<endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Why x which is enum in class is accessible using scope resolution operator in main function?

Comment: Because that's the way the C++ language is defined.

Comment: @GregHewgill ok..for which other datatypes this is valid ?

Comment: @niting112 all other datatypes and typedefs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you are asking why you do not have to instantiate a `Sample` to access `x`. The reason is that `enum`s are like `typedef`s: they create a new type, they don't create a variable. You can access `Sample::x` the same way you could access a `typedef` or a `struct`/`class` declaration inside the class.

Comment: Thanks!! Yes my doubt is exactly what you said. But sorry I didn't understand the line "You can access Sample::x the same way you could access a typedef or a struct/class declaration inside the class."

Comment: @niting112 for instance, if you do `struct A { struct B { }; };` you can do `A::B b;`

Comment: @SethCarnegie If it's not a variable but just a type, how does it store a value? I can use ``` int i = Sample::x ``` right?

Answer (score 1):

Because the `enum` is defined in `public` area. Comment `public` keyword, and you wont be able to access it. Same goes for any `typedef` you declare in public/non-public area.

Answer (score 0):

Because `enum`s in CPP has *internal linkage* by default i.e. they are made *private* if you declare them in `struct or class`. So you have to use `::` (*scope resolution operator*) to access *enumerators(enum constants).*

In C, you can access *enumerators* directly because they are *global* by default.